# select rows for which dates of the same columns are in 7 days groups

Tags: sql, date, diff

For the following table (called table) I would like to create a column called 'trans_flag' which indicates the rows (trans_number per client) which are the most recent for every group of 7 days. The problem is that 7 days are not fixed but it starts when the last occurance of previous group ends. Example below.

```
trans_number    client      trans_date  
-----------------------------------------------------
abc001          client1     2019-07-23
abc003          client1     2019-06-05      
abc005          client1     2019-05-30          
abc007          client1     2019-05-28          
abc012          client1     2019-05-20          
abc018          client1     2019-05-16      
abc020          client1     2019-05-15          
abc023          client1     2019-05-14          
abc027          client1     2019-05-13      
abc028          client1     2019-04-16          
abc032          client1     2019-04-15
```

I already created the column date_diff which indicates the difference between corresponding dates of column 'trans_date'.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT trans_number, client, trans_date,
        -ISNULL(DATEDIFF(day,
                    (SELECT MIN(trans_date)
                     FROM table
                     WHERE client= T.client AND trans_date> T.trans_date),
                    trans_date),
           0) date_diff
FROM table T
WHERE client = 123
ORDER BY trans_date DESC
```

```
trans_number    client      trans_date  date_diff
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
abc001          client1     2019-07-23      0
abc003          client1     2019-06-05      48
abc005          client1     2019-05-30      6
abc007          client1     2019-05-28      2
abc012          client1     2019-05-20      8
abc018          client1     2019-05-16      4
abc020          client1     2019-05-15      1
abc023          client1     2019-05-14      1
abc027          client1     2019-05-13      1
abc028          client1     2019-04-16      27
abc032          client1     2019-04-15      1
```

The aim is to look on the client level at the most recent date and then back for the last 7 days to get the record with the most recent date in such a group. The next iteration should start with the next record which is not in the group of 7 days for previous iteration.

```
trans_number    client      trans_date  date_diff   trans_flag
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
abc001          client1     2019-07-23      0       1
abc003          client1     2019-06-05      48      1
abc005          client1     2019-05-30      6       0
abc007          client1     2019-05-28      2       1
abc012          client1     2019-05-20      8       1
abc018          client1     2019-05-16      4       0
abc020          client1     2019-05-15      1       0
abc023          client1     2019-05-14      1       0
abc027          client1     2019-05-13      1       1
abc028          client1     2019-04-16      27      1
abc032          client1     2019-04-15      1       0
```

Little explanation on the example above.

1) Transaction abc001 is the most recent for that client, so has flag = 1

2) Transaction abc003 occured more than 7 days before abc001 so has flag = 1

3) Transaction abc005 occured less than 7 days before abc003 so has flag = 0

4) Transaction abc007 has flag 1 because abc003 is the record indicated by previous group and the date difference between abc007 and abc003 is more than 7 days (abc005 is omitted because of abc003).

How to create 'trans_flag' column?

Comment: SELECT date_diff   - lag(date_diff ) OVER (ORDER BY trans_num) FROM table this should get you previous value then you can use some case statement to get your business logic like > 7 or <7 to flag it

Comment: Hi nithin, thanks for reply. LAG function looks only on one row (user may choose on which by setting the offset paramether). This will not help me to flag correctly all rows, for example trans_number abc007 because lag will return 2 but actually it is 8 based on point 4) in my initial quesion.